# Missing objects when building Unity3d game for WebGL using game.ci for GitLab

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab, game-development, cicd

I was given a Unity3d game to setup a pipeline in GitLab for if targeting WebGL. I'm using [Game.ci](https://game.ci/docs/gitlab/getting-started) guide and this is already working/setup but after the build completes, we've noticed that a few objects are missing in the scene.

Reviewing the log output, I found we have a few lines like this that may or may not be the issue but it's the only I can find from the logs so far:

```
Starting: /opt/unity/Editor/Data/bee_backend --profile="Library/Bee/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --stdin-canary --dagfile="Library/Bee/2000b0aE.dag" --continue-on-failure ScriptAssemblies
WorkingDir: <working-dir>
ExitCode: 4 Duration: 0s42ms
[             ] Require frontend run.  Library/Bee/2000b0aE.dag couldn't be loaded
```

It's complaining about `Library/Bee/2000b0aE.dag` but further down the logs I can see it gives no error for that file :

```
Starting: /opt/unity/Editor/Data/bee_backend --profile="Library/Bee/backend_profiler1.traceevents" --stdin-canary --dagfile="Library/Bee/2000b0aE.dag" --continue-on-failure --dagfilejson="Library/Bee/2000b0aE.dag.json" ScriptAssemblies
WorkingDir: <working-dir>
ExitCode: 0 Duration: 52s
```

I've tried to find info about this but the closest I could find was [Linux editor stuck on loading because of bee_backend w/ workaround](https://forum.unity.com/threads/linux-editor-stuck-on-loading-because-of-bee_backend-w-workaround.1166347/) which states that the `--stdin-canary` arg is the problem but I didn't see an `ExitCode: 4` (or non-zero for that matter)

Any thoughts on this would be more than appreciated. Thanks in advance!